# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of object:[image]

and i want to get property from array in array:[image]

i use v-for for iterate through an array of "publication" :

```
<tbody v-for="elem in cart.publication">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><a href="#" class="text-danger"><i class="ri-delete-bin-3-line"></i></a></td>
      <td><img :src="elem.images[0].url" class="img-fluid" width="35" alt="product"></td>
</tbody>
```

but i get error message:`vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Comment: In the above JSON I don't see an object labeled "cart". Make sure that in your corresponding component that said cart is actually valid. Assuming the JSON you posted is the the whole response, won't it be "elem in publication"

Comment: see if you are able to get the data in images  use this code:`<div v-for="elem in cart.publication"><span>{{elem.images.length}}</span></div>`

Comment: I think the other array item doesn't have the image array?

Comment: Assuming the full object is `cart`, then `elem.images[0].url` is indeed correct– but if you have *any* publication elements that have an empty array, you'll get that error (because you're effectively referencing `(undefined).url`). You need to guard against the case where images is missing/ empty.

Comment: @DenIsahac, Yes, you are right. i was sure, that other time had image array, but it is not so

Answer (score 0):

You could write a computed property with safe navigation operators (?.)

```
computed: {
 imageUrls() {
   return this.cart.publication?.map(pub => pub.images?.[0]?.url) ?? [];
 }
}

...

<tbody v-for="url in imageUrls">
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td><a href="#" class="text-danger"><i class="ri-delete-bin-3-line"></i></a></td>
  <td><img :src="url" class="img-fluid" width="35" alt="product"></td>
</tbody>
```